# WooCommerce: How can I add a certain product to the cart and redirect to the cart from a non-shop page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to promote a certain product on a non-shop page. I want to have a `Buy now` link on that page, which, when clicked, would add the product to the cart and automatically reload the page and redirect the customer to the cart. This should be done only for that certain product and should not be enabled for all products (so the `Redirect to the cart page after successful addition` option should NOT be set to TRUE).

Answer (score 0):

You can create "add to cart" links for WooCommerce using this pattern on simple links:

```
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=<product ID>&quantity=<number of quantity>
```

This example will work with simple products.
If you want to use products with variations you need to add some more values to the URL like:

```
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&variation_id=456&attribute_pa_colour=black
```

If you enter the slug of the cart page in this url, here: `/cart/`, it should redirect to the cart.

To add a product to the cart without redirecting:

```
http://example.com/?add-to-cart=<product ID>
```